# How to sort through list of a list and remove a list if less not least value

Tags: python, list

Currently, this takes the list of the candidates and sorts it so that the candidates with the lowest score are in the first positions, how would I get it so that it checks each list and if the number in the second field is not equal to the first one it deletes this list? 
I am trying to remove all lists that are not the lowest or equal lowest number in candidate [x][1]:

```
candidates = [[name, 3, characteristic], [name, 7, characteristic], [name, 3, characteristic]]
```

so the following code should only delete candidates [1]

```
from operator import itemgetter

candidates.sort(key=itemgetter(1))

for [x][1] in candidates:
    if candidates[x][1] != candidates[0][1] :
        candidates.remove(candidates[x])
```

Thanks!

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you could use the `filter()` function to do this

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure how to implement that for a list of a list though, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that you are modifying the `candidates` list while iterating over the very same list. This causes problems as you probably noticed.

Rather than `sorted()` you can use [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) with a key to determine the item with the least value. This gives better performance - O(n) vs. O(n log n) - which might be important if there is a long list of candidates.

Furthermore, you would be better off determining the minimum value upfront, store it in a variable, and use that in a list comprehension/filter when comparing items. This avoids multiple redundant calls to `min()` resulting in a more efficient solution:

```
from operator import itemgetter

candidates = [['name', 97, 'blah'], ['name', 7, 'candidate'], ['name', 3, 'characteristic'], ['name', 3, 'characteristic']]

min_value = min(candidates, key=itemgetter(1))[1]
candidates = [candidate for candidate in candidates if candidate[1] == min_value]
print(candidates)
# [['name', 3, 'characteristic'], ['name', 3, 'characteristic']]
```

Note that I use a list comprehension here. They are considered more Pythonic, may have better performance, and can easily be changed into generator expressions which can also yield better performance in many situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, if I don't misunderstand your meaning:

```
from operator import itemgetter
candidates = [['name', 3, 'characteristic'], ['name', 7, 'characteristic'], ['name', 3, 'characteristic']]

candidates=filter(lambda x:x[1]==sorted(candidates,key=itemgetter(1))[0][1],candidates)

print(candidates)
```

Use `filter()` method to remove the sublist, if the second field is not equal to the lowest score.

If you're using Python3.x, you should use `list(filter(...))`

Output:

```
[['name', 3, 'characteristic'], ['name', 3, 'characteristic']]
```

---

**Update**

I forgot that you can use `min()` to get the lowest score, it is an more efficient way:

```
candidates = [['name', 3, 'characteristic'], ['name', 7, 'characteristic'], ['name', 3, 'characteristic']]

candidates=list(filter(lambda x:x[1]==min([i[1] for i in candidates]),candidates))

print(candidates)
```

Comment: This is now returning <filter object at 0x1104137f0>, any ideas?

Comment: @TimJames In Python3.x, you should use `list(filter(...))` to convert the result to list.

Comment: This is not efficient - the list is sorted once for each item in the list. Sort once and save the result and, better, use `min()`.

Comment: @mhawke Yeah, that's an more efficient way, I update my answer.